# Tkinter: Treeview com valores repetidos após apertar botão "consultar"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3, treeview

Todas as vezes que pressiono o botão "Consultar" a treeview atualiza, mas também adicionando as rows anteriores.

```
    def consultar(): 
    #função que Mostra na treeview todos os produtos cadastrados
                    conn = sqlite3.connect('banco_produtos_cadastrados.db')
                    bd = conn.cursor()
                    bd.execute("SELECT * FROM produtos")
                    rows = bd.fetchall()
                    for row in rows:
                        print(row) # Mostra toda tabela
                        tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)

tree= ttk.Treeview(janela2, column=( "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5","column6"), show='headings')
ttk.Style().configure(tree, background = "black", foreground="white", fieldbackground="red")

tree.heading("#1", text="código")
tree.heading("#2", text="Produto")
tree.heading("#3", text="Marca")
tree.heading("#4", text="Fornecedor")
tree.heading("#5", text="Preço")
tree.heading("#6", text="Preço do fornecedor")    
tree.pack()
```

Comment: Não seria o caso de limpar a arvore antes de uma nova consulta? Ou criar um algorítimo capaz de checar os itens excedentes? Não entendi o seu problema.

Comment: sim, realmente seria o caso de limpar a arvore. poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: [Isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812134/how-to-clear-an-entire-treeview-with-tkinter) te ajuda?

Comment: Problema resolvido. Mega agradecido!

Comment: Ótimo! Sinta-se a vontade para publicar a resposta ou excluir a pergunta se considerar que ela é muito específica para servir a outros usuários.